# error con session_start(): e if variable rol

Tags: php, web, aplicación-web, php5, session

Buenas tardes tengo un inconveniente con los if y session_start();

intento hacer es que cuando  no este iniciada la sesion solo vean en el menu la palabra **inicia sesion**

y en la tabla mas abajo no aparezcan los botones de **solicitar y eliminar**.. y cuando inicie sesion segun el rol solo aparezca **solicitar o eliminar**.

cuando inicio sesion en el menu sale esto

notice
: Undefined index: rol in
C:\xampp\htdocs\curso\menu\menu.php
on line
49

inicia sesion

Notice
: Undefined index: rol in
C:\xampp\htdocs\curso\menu\menu.php
on line
60

Notice
: Undefined index: rol in
C:\xampp\htdocs\curso\menu\menu.php
on line
69

---

codigo de  el menu

```
<?php

include('basedatos/conexion.php');

  $n=$bd->query("SELECT * from usuario INNER JOIN rol on rol.rol_id_rol = rol.rol_id '");

 session_start();

 if (isset ($_SESSION['cedula'] ) ) {

  $a = $_SESSION['cedula'];
  $b = $_SESSION['rol'];
  $c = $_SESSION['nombre'];

  }else{

 $a ="";
 $b = "";
 $c = "";
 }



 49)    <?php   if ($_SESSION['rol'] !== '') {    ?>

<a class="nav-link" style="color:black" href="login.php" > inicia sesion</a> 

  <?php  }     ?>

 60)   <?php if ($_SESSION['rol'] !== '1') { ?>

<a class="nav-link"  href="login.php" style="color:white;">   <?php echo  $a; ?> </a></li>

 69)   <?php } if ($_SESSION['rol'] !== '2') { ?>


<a class="nav-link"  href="login.php" style="color:white;"> a  <?php echo  $c; ?> </a></li> <?php }  ?>
```

----------------------------codigo de la tabla-------------------------------------

```
$n=$bd->query("SELECT * from usuario INNER JOIN rol on rol.rol_id_rol = rol.rol_id '");

session_estart();

if(isset($_SESSION['cedula']))
{

  $a = $_SESSION['nombre'];
  $b = $_SESSION['rol'];
  $c = $_SESSION['cedula'];


}selse{

 $a ="";
 $b = "";
 $c = "";


}


48 ) <?php if ($_SESSION['rol'] !==' ') { ?>



<th scope="col" colspan="2"style="text-align:center"><label >Accion</label></th>


<?php } ?>

54)  <?php if ($_SESSION['rol'] !=='1') { ?>`

<th scope="col" colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><label >Accion</label></th>
```

```
 61)          <?php   if ($_SESSION['rol'] !== '2') { ?>


         <?php } 

      
         ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate de usar `isset()` para evitar ese error si la variable no existe en la `$_SESSION` Ejemplo: `<?php   if (isset($_SESSION['rol']) {   ?>`

Aquí puedes ver mas detalles de isset(): https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_var_isset.asp

Comment: El isset lo use en  if al principio del cod donde digo si existen el usuario muestre u si  o deja un espacio vacio despues del session estart

Comment: Donde sale "Undefined" tienes que usarlo otra vez, recuerda que ```isset()``` determina si la variable esta declarada o no

Comment: ¿En qué parte de tu código asignas un valor para la clave `rol` en la variable `$_SESSION`? Recuerda que `$_SESSION` es un array, tú estás buscando en ella un valor bajo una clave que no existe, por eso el *`Undefined index`*